# jQuery CoffeeScript - learning

Tags: jquery, coffeescript

I am trying to use `jQuery` with `CoffeScript`. I was following the instructions form a blog which indicated to use **$ ->** or **jQuery ->** instead of .ready() . I played around with the code a bit but I can't seem to understand what I am getting wrong. Just trying to learn a little bit.

Here is the code that works in `jQuery`:

```
$(document).ready( function() {
$("span.today").closest("td").css("background-color", "#7792ad")
});
```

Here is what I was expecting to work in `CoffeScript`:

```
$ ->
$("span.today").closest("td").css("background-color", "#7792ad")
```

It doesn't work though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
$ ->
    $("span.today").closest("td").css("background-color", "#7792ad");
```

> A general principle is that many unnecessary parentheses and braces can be dropped because **indention can be used instead of braces to denote blocks of code**